# Google Driving Directions Gadget Alternative

Tags: google-maps, google-gadget, driving-directions

Does anyone know what's going on with the [Google Driving Directions Gadget](http://www.google.com/ig/directory?synd=open&q=maps)?

If you click the add a gadget to your website and you just get a 404.
I have it on a page here, and if I open chrome developer tools I get:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/f…&lang=en&country=US&border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&output=js Failed to load
```

On [this page](http://key4design.co.uk/goldengrove/home/home.php?&page=3).

Does anyone know a working alternative or a work around for this? It's strange that Google would let something like this break.

If you click the google maps gadget above that too, it also gives a 404. It has been like that for the last few days that I have tried it, so not sure how long its been like that for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those gadgets are by third party developers.  From the bottom of the page you link to:

> Much of the content in this directory was developed by other companies or by Google's users, not by Google. Google makes no promises or representations about its performance, quality, or content. Google doesn't charge for inclusion in this directory or accept payment for better placement.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, looks like I might need to write something using the google maps api myself argh, not what I want as its more work, where as it was working just fine before.